# How can you say "We have to let you go", in the context of firing somebody?

Tags: translation

In English,

"Sorry, we have to let you go" is a nice way to tell somebody they are fired

If you directly translate it, it becomes 
"我们必须让你走", which doesn't seem right

What are some ways to fire somebody in the nicest way possible?

Comment: On zhihu https://www.zhihu.com/question/30796600?sort=created someone asked 如何委婉的辞退员工？ (What's a tactful way to fire an employee?) the most upvoted answer says: 世界那么大，我想让你去看看 (The world's a big place, I want to let you go have a look).

Comment: I'm not HR or the boss, I may say: “我们暂时没有合适的职位给您”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"我们必须让你走" is correct literally, but sounds straightforward.

You can use "不得不" instead of "必须" because it's more passive; and use "离开" instead of "走" to make the sentence euphemistic. e.g.

> 我们不得不让你离开公司

Or make it more euphemistic by using "可能需要" (may need), (if you don't stick to the original English sentence and its translation)

> 我们可能需要你离开公司

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is "很抱歉，公司決定不再留你"

- 很抱歉 (regretfully) - *express sympathy*
- 公司決定 (the company decided)- *saying 'the company decided' instead of 'we decided' to imply it is not a personal decision, no one in the company wanted this to happen.*
- 不再留你 (no longer keeping you) - *instead of telling someone that he has to leave, telling him the company can no longer stop him from leaving, implying he will have many job options elsewhere (maintain his dignity). It is for his own good that the company let him go.*